# How to restrict what components can be added to an Experience Fragment XF

Tags: aem

How do you control which components you can add to an Experience Fragment? Normally I use an XML (.content.xml) in designs but I'm not sure where to do this for Experience Fragment.

I have a component with a parsys that can only allow certain components to be added. Once I add this component to an Experience Fragment those restrictions disappear and authors can add any component that is allowed on the XF. How can I make the Experience Fragment follow the restrictions?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @ronnyfm yes, I created a policy for dynamic experience fragment to restrict what can be placed in component parsys. it can only be done for dynamic XF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer: policies can be added for dynamic experience fragment templates only. A policy needs to be added to the dynamic experience fragment.

1. In AEM: go to Tools > General > Templates > Select your Template > select component > click policy icon > create policy
2. Manually, in CRXDE can be created in /conf/..wcm/policies/.content.xml and associated to your dynamic experience fragment in /conf/../yourtemplate (make sure the policy numbers match to associate).